# How many rational points on $F(x,y)=m$ for homogeneous $F$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ be homogeneous of degree $d$ and $m$ is rational.

Assume the curve $C : F(x,y)=m$ is irreducible and of genus greater
than one.

Currently, how many rational points $C$ can have in terms of $d$?

Trivial lower bound is $d$.

IIRC, without any restrictions on $F$, it is possible about constant times 
$g^2$, where $g$ is the genus.